# ConnectivityManager NullPointerException while backporting an application

Tags: java, android, java-7, backport

I am backporting an Android application from Android 9 to Android 5.1

Now i got to the point that i get the error

```
 Process: com.name.systemhealthmonitor, PID: 3369
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.name.systemhealthmonitor.services.RealtimeMonitorService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest, android.net.ConnectivityManager$NetworkCallback)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2771)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1386)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest, android.net.ConnectivityManager$NetworkCallback)' on a null object reference
    at com.name.systemhealthmonitor.NetworkMonitor.start(NetworkMonitor.java:67)
    at com.name.systemhealthmonitor.services.RealtimeMonitorService.onCreate(RealtimeMonitorService.java:72)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2761)
```

The code causing this is

```
public void start() {
    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mCm.registerNetworkCallback(new NetworkRequest.Builder().build(), mNetworkCallback);
}
```

Is this a problem related to the lower API version used or lack of Java 8?
Not sure how to progress further here

Thanks!

Comment: what is mCm?  is it initialized? you can not call a method(registerNetworkCallback) on an object if that object is not initialized!

Comment: Good question, i just now have seen that i added before an IF check for the android version
 ____
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mCm = appContext.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
            mTelephonyManager = appContext.getSystemService(TelephonyManager.class);
            mWifiManager = appContext.getSystemService(WifiManager.class);
        }
_____
but i see that those require API level 23 and i have to use 22

Comment: I see that i can use the getSystemService by passing a string in API level 22.
What i did was

 mCm = (ConnectivityManager) appContext.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class.toString());
but i still end with the same error